# How to maximize total revenue on constant elasticy curve

Tags: elasticity

So to maximize total revenue, we sell at the price on the demand elasticity curve where elasticity=1 right? Lets say on one curve, the elasticity throughout the curve is equal to 1.5? How much should we decrease the price?

Comment: (-1) This question does not show any research effort. If one understands the logic behind the elasticty 1 thing, one can answer the question easily.

Comment: Elasticity is not constant even with a linear demand curve.

Answer (score 0):

Pick any point on the demand curve. If you were to increase price by $x$ percent, the quantity sold will decrease by $1.5x$ percent.

- If you increase price, what will happen to your total revenue? Will it go up or down?
- If you decrease price, what will happen to your total revenue?

Move your point $x$ in the direction that will increase your TR. Do the same thing over and over again. [This link](https://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ConstantPriceElasticityOfDemand/) might also help you visualize and understand more.